# How can I detect the completion of multiple simultaneous animations on many elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a rather complicated setup with two columns full of elements.
Clicking on one element opens up a 'details' section under it, closes any other previously opened details section in this column, filters the other list and opens 'details' sections under the remaining elements of the other column.

This is rather heavy for the user so I'm trying to animate all this and separate it into many steps or waves so that the user can understand what's going on.

Wave 1: Simultaneously

- close the details sections under all elements
- fade in elements which were hidden

Wave 2: Simultaneously

- open the clicked element's details section
- fade out certain elements in the other column

Wave 3: Simultaneously

- open a details section under the remaining elements of the other column

I normally use the callback function of the `animate` method to start the second animation when the first one finishes, but since I'm waiting for multiple animations to finish, this approach doesn't work. Also, these animations affect many elements, so using `queue: false` doesn't exactly fit the bill.

How can I detect the completion of multiple simultaneous animations on many elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jQuery's "when" and "done" methods. they can be used to aggregate multiple "deffered" object like the ones animate returns.
Example :

```
$.when(
   $('#A').animate({height : 100}), 
   $('#B').animate({width : 50})
).done(function() { alert('All Done!') })
```

Comment: I used this also with function that don't return deferred objects. I just made those functions return true and they worked all the same. This is perfect because it allowed me to blend custom functions and jQuery functions easily within the `when` clause.

Comment: Damn, I was wrong, this does not work when you're not getting a deferred object returned to you by the functions in the `when` method. Can I make custom functions which return deferred objects?

Comment: You need to have objects that have the promise function. Such are the deferred objects and the jQuery objects. I don't understand what kind of other methods you need. In your question you asked for animations so that should work as I've shown in my example

Comment: You can make your functions return `(new $.Deferred()).resolve()` if you want them to be automatically resolved. But why not just leaving them out of the "when" method?

Comment: To answer your question, have a look at my javascript: http://shawninder.99k.org/js/myScripts.js. You will see a section with comments like `Wave 1`, `Wave 2`, etc. where I launch multiple functions in waves, waiting for their completion before launching the second wave. Some of these functions return deferred objects, like `toggle`. For the others, like `allEyesOff`, I've created a `Deferred()` object, called `resolve()` as appropriate inside the function and return the deferred object's `promise()` method: `return deferredObject.promise();` Make sense?

Comment: It should work but you don't need to call the resolve method yourself but rather give a "resolved" deferred object. i.e. `return deferredObject.resolve()`

Answer (score 3):

For each of your animations your are starting, create a jQuery deferred object:

```
var animDf1 = jQuery.Deferred();
var animDf2 = jQuery.Deferred();
...
```

Inside the callback in the animations, resolve that callback:

```
$('#thing1').fadeOut(500, function() {
    var animDf1.resolve();
});
```

Combine each group of deferred objects with the 'when' function:

```
// Wave 1:
$.when(animDf1, animDf2, animDf3, ...).then(function() {
    // They are all done.  Time for the next thing
    Wave2Start();
});
```

Remember that a Deferred can only be resolved (or rejected) exactly one time.  If all these animations repeat, you will need to create new jQuery.Deferred objects to handle the next time.

**Update**: As mentioned in comments by idanzalz, you may not need to create a separate deferred object since you can use the return of the animation function itself as the deferred object:

```
var animDf1 = $('#thing1').fadeOut(500);
var animDf2 = $('#thing2').fadeOut(500);

$.when(animDf1, animDf2).then(function() {
    // animations are done... what's next?
});
```

Whether or not you can use this method will depend on your code structure, and whether you are applying multiple animations to the same object.  My first suggestion above lets you control each .resolve() explicitly.

Comment: Why not use the result of the animate call as the deferred object?

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you mean?  The effects functions (e.g. fadeOut) return the jQuery object, not a deferred object.  If you use $.when() on an object (other than a jQuery.Deferred), it will immediately be resolved.  (Or am I wrong?)

Comment: A jquery object is not a deferred object but it still has the "promise" method which is what we need here. The default context of the promise is the "fx" context which means it will be resolved when all animations on the object have resolved. see [this](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) for more information

Comment: Thanks idanzalz.  Good info.  I've updated my answer with the more concise method you suggested (in addition to the drawn out, but more explicit method I originally wrote).

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval to query the elements in question and see if `:animated` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global counter initialized at 0. When an animation starts increment it. When an animation finishes decrement it and if it is back to 0 run the master handler that should be executed when all animations finish.

Comment: This might have a race condition if some animation finishes before another starts

Comment: In that case if the number of animations are known from the start the counter can be initialized to that and then only decremented. If the number of animations is unknown and there is the possibility of the counter reaching 0 before the last animation finishes, this algorithm should still be usable but with modifications to match the specific problem.